# Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A NO WIFI INTERNET

Tags: samsung, intel-wireless

The connection is established but there is no internet connection at all. My NIC is a Intel ultimate-n 6300. Sometimes it connects but very slow! I'm not really sure what commands i have read will work.

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with some Intel wireless cards (that use the `iwlwifi` driver) and the Wireless N implementation on some routers.  Often you can get the Wifi working well by simply disabling N.

You can try running the following commands.  If these work, download [this script](https://github.com/FreedomBen/handy-bash-scripts/blob/master/fixTheInternet.bash) and run it each time you boot up.  You can [set it up to run automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu) if you'd prefer.  Run these:

```
lsmod | grep iwlwifi
```

If you don't get anything out, then you aren't using the `iwlwifi` driver and the following steps will not work unless you replace "iwlwifi" with the driver in use.

If you do get something back, run these commands:

```
# Put eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 down

# Remove iwlwifi module
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi

# Reinstert iwlwifi module with n disabled
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

If these work, there is [a script here](https://github.com/FreedomBen/handy-bash-scripts/blob/master/fixTheInternet.bash) you can use for the future:  https://github.com/FreedomBen/handy-bash-scripts/blob/master/fixTheInternet.bash