# Samsung NP900X3E No WiFi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, samsung

A few weeks ago, I switched from Windows8 to **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS** on my Sasmung **NP900X3E**-K02DE.

Everything worked, except the WiFi. The problem was, that connecting to networks (home, work, hotspot and university) sometimes took up to 2 minutes, sometimes I could connect immediately and sometimes i couldn't connect at all. I had to switch WiFi off and back on or connect to another network, before it worked again.

So I tried various things to get rid of this problem, mainly I tried different drivers and settings ( like this: [samsung-series-9-np900x3a-no-wifi-internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357354/samsung-series-9-np900x3a-no-wifi-internet) ). Unfortunately I can't remember everything I did.

Long story short: Since this morning, my WiFi adapter isn't found at all. There is no possibility to (de)activate it through UI, there are no wifi networks shown and I can't find wlan0 in terminal.

Here is a copy of my [wireless-info.txt](http://www.pasteall.org/61405/text)

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance, 
Fitzi.

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears that you have loaded the wrong driver. Let's remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Also, in the version of *iwlwifi* that is included in kernel version 3.19-xx, there is a great deal more in the file iwlwifi.conf. Apparently, it has been overwritten. Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Amend the file to read:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs     /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

I doubt that you need the other options. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

I notice in your paste that there are at least four access points with the same name. I suspect that the dropping may be because your wireless card is roaming from among them. I suggest you ask Network Manager to bind to the strongest one as described here: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't solve my problems =/
I tried booting from a live usb stick in the meantime, to make sure it's no hardware fault, thank god it isn't.

Comment: Here is a new wireless-info: http://www.pasteall.org/61413. I noticed, that the country code is still 00, altough i changed it in the crda file.

If you have any other idea what could cause my problem, I'd be very happy. Otherwise I'l have to install a fresh copy of ubuntu.

Comment: May we see: `cat  /etc/default/crda` Also, is the result the same with the tether disconnected?

Comment: The results where the same with and without tether connected.
Unfortunately I can't say anything else, because I already installed a new copy of ubuntu, so my WiFi is working again (with the mentioned connection problems).
Anyway, thank you very much for your help (:

Comment: Do my suggestions above help the connection problem at all?

Comment: I did not have any connection problems so far.  But I'd probably need a few more days to say something exactly.
I'm going to report if it still works in a few days.

Comment: I still have those connection problems (at home and via hotspot at least) but it may be possible that the connection problems occur after suspending the lid only.

Comment: Okay, it has nothing to do with suspending. The problem occures after restarting too. =/

Comment: Since you have now made the changes I suggested, may we see a new wireless-info with the wireless connected in order to try to spot a cause for the drops?

Comment: Of course. Here is a new one http://www.pasteall.org/61502/text .
It feels like the connection problems occur much less frequent since your suggested changes.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Binding to one AP is not my preferred solution, because in office I often need so switch to different rooms where I still need wifi.
Also at university I can't bind to any AP, because of constantly switching rooms. Also at home there is only one AP and still problems connecting to it sometimes. I actually just had those problems again and made this new wireless-info right after I finally could connect to university wifi (after restarting and switching wifi on and off multiple times): http://www.pasteall.org/61520/text

Comment: here is one right after a sudden disconnect http://www.pasteall.org/61521/text